# Can't get a function working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot get a function working when using class tag. Tried with ID and worked properly, but I need it with a class. The one which is not working is the input class="nextButton".

Here is a part of my HTML code:

```
<div class="wrap">  
            <h3>Question2</h3>
                <p>Which National Team won the first World Cup?</p>
                    <div class="wraptext">
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Brazil" /><strong>Brazil</strong><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="France" /><strong>France</strong><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Italy" /><strong>Italy</strong><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="question2" value="Uruguay" /><strong>Uruguay</strong><br />
                        <input class="nextButton" type="button" value="Next Question">
                        <input class="prevButton" type="button" value="Previous Question">
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap");
var start = document.getElementById("startB");
var next = document.getElementsByClassName("nextButton");

for (var i = 0; i<questions.length; i++) {
  questions[i].style.display="none"
}

start.addEventListener("click", showQuestions);

function showQuestions(){
  questions[0].style.display="";
}

next.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion);

function nextQuestion(){
  alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: please add the code in text form to the question.

Comment: And try opening your console (hit F12). You'll see an error which will give you a big hint about your problem. Trying doing `console.log(next)`.

Comment: `next` is not a `HTMLElement` it is a collection of elements, it doesn't have `addEventListener` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax..

`var next = document.getElementsByClassName('nextButton')[0];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are treating getElementsByClassName as if it returns a single value rather than an array.

Either loop through the array or add a [0] to only reference the first element it returns.